# Azure DevOps Authentication (multi-tenant)

Tags: azure, devops, azure-service-principal, azure-app-registration

I have strange question.

I have two Azure tenants. Let's say "Tenant A" and "Tenant B" and there is an Azure DevOps "linked" to Tenant A—let's call it "DevOps A". I have an app registration resource in Tenant A, which is a multi-tenant. In Tenant B, I have a service principle linked to the app registration in Tenant A, and I also have a user in Tenant B. This user is invited to DevOps A, and he can access it. Everything is normal for now. But when I try to get the Azure DevOps groups in DevOps A, for example, via the REST API, I am getting this message: :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">




<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>

        Azure DevOps Services | Sign In

    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;&#32;IE=10;&#32;IE=9;&#32;IE=8" />
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico" />

    <link data-bundlelength="516193" data-bundlename="commoncss"
        data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M226_20230814.3/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-commoncss-vCZ9D6UIO_qlhG7RrGLDp5ecIS_cunZt7_o3iwWt7lrU="
        data-includedstyles="jQueryUI-Modified;Core;Splitter;PivotView"
        href="/_static/tfs/M226_20230814.3/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-commoncss-v-iQu887NdMc5JZJk3qLWWPIguQy4zWErrDkgvWr3S8s="
        rel="stylesheet" />
    <link data-bundlelength="117304" data-bundlename="viewcss"
        data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M226_20230814.3/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-viewcss-vuZc8-qj8Ccsk2Id3aYU0dLxPmsvgd6StlyaYitm0xxU="
        data-includedstyles="VSS.Controls"
        href="/_static/tfs/M226_20230814.3/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-viewcss-vZeWfVvRTo2a7DO4ptMBi0cCBa3W_gjANgU36Es8paWQ="
        rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--UxServices customizations -->

    <link href="/_static/tfs/M226_20230814.3/_content/Authentication.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
....
```

I am using a bearer token for authentication for the REST API, generated using user credentials and app registration credentials, but I get the same result.

I created a third tenant, "Tenant C" and linked him to "DevOps C". Then I tried to use the REST API with the user, from the Tenant C, and it worked.

I don't know why when I include the service principle and user from another tenant, it throws this message.

Please Help.